# Is it possible to improve code completion relative to dictionaries in PyCharm?

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm, code-completion

In PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3:

If I declare a dict and add key/value pairs one by one like so:

```
a_dict = {}
a_dict['key_1'] = 'val_1'
a_dict['key_2'] = 'val_2'
a_dict['']  # Code completion works!
```

code completion works. That is, I can write a_dict[''] and press Ctrl+space and get a list of keys to select from. However, if I define the dictionary like so:

```
a_dict = {'key_1': 'val_1', 'key_2':'val_2'}
a_dict['']  # No code completion
```

code completion does not work.

Also, if the first example is implemented in the global scope, code completion only works in the global scope. That is, in local scope code completion does not work even when using the global keyword:

```
def some_func():
    global a_dict
    a_dict['']  # No code completion
```

Are there ways to get PyCharm to perform code_completion in these cases?

Edit: If you don't use the *global* keyword in local scope (you do not need it in cases where you only reference the global variable, but do not change it) code completion does work.

Comment: Not a definitive answer but I don't think this will be possible outside of developing a plugin. [This JetBrains Code Completion SDK guide](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/code_completion.html) might be helpful.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce only the third case in [the latest EAP](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/). You could file an issue in [the tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) or contribute to [this file](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/codeInsight/completion/PyDictKeyNamesCompletionContributor.java).